# Displaying Name from Browser link

Tags: javascript, html

is possible for example, to put this on browser

https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html + one X name, let's say Pedro

and once it opens it has a text

Automatically replace this with the name from domain link

So it would say,

Hi "Pedro", is possible? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you can pass it as a query (i.e. `https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html?Pedro`), you should then be able to do something like this:

```
var name = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1));
document.getElementById("nameHolder").innerHTML = "<h3>" + name + "</h3>";
```

Where you have some HTML element with an `id` of `nameHolder`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following if your url looks like this.

> https://www.example.com/Pedro

In order to ensure the DOM has loaded wrap it in a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

    let name = window.alert(this.href.substr(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
    let new_h3 = document.createElement('h3');
    new_h3.innerHTML = `Hi ${name}`;
    document.getElementById("nameHolder").appendChild(new_h3); 

});
```

or else you could do the following which is a bit more succinct.

```
let name = window.alert(this.href.substr(this.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
document.getElementById("nameHolder")..innerHTML = "<h3>" + `Hi ${name}` + "</h3>";
```

Comment: thanks Paul!! but I can place it within an <h3> inside of a <div>?

Comment: Sorry @Paul Fitzgerald correct 

    <div id="nameHolder">
         <h3 class="nameStyle"></h3>
    </div>